# ¿Cómo puedo contar el número consecutivo de días sin lluvias, con separación por mes?

Tags: r

Tengo un archivo con 3 columnas de fecha (Día, mes, año) y otras 26 con información de precipitación diaria por estación... 
Uso la función dw.spell,

```
year_min <- 1949
year_max <- 2017

period <- inp$A.O>=year_min & inp$A.O<=year_max
station <- names(inp)[!(names(inp) %in% c("day","month","year"))]

prec_mes <- inp[period,station]

nn <- dw.spell(data = prec_mes,valmin = 0,origin = "1949-05-19",extract = NULL)
nnd <- dw.spell(data = prec_mes,valmin = 0,origin = "1949-05-19",extract ="dry" )
```

Pero me genera spell lengths de más de 31 días o de la cantidad del mes respectivo.

Como los puedo generar solo para la duración de un mes???

Comment: Bienvenido user88544 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: `dw.spell` te retorna las longitudes absolutas de cada intervalo independientemente que cambie o no el mes. En el caso que el intervalo cambie de mes, ¿Que es lo que quisieras hacer? ¿hacer que llegue hasta el final y luego abrir el mismo en el siguiente mes?